# scheduleAtFixedRate won't shut down?

Tags: java

I have a bot that, when I send a command, I want to invoke a task using `scheduleAtFixedRate`. When I send a different command, I want the `scheduleAtFixedRate` to be shut down. Here is my code:

```
Future<?> future;
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor eventPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

if (message.equals("!www")) {
     future = eventPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, 0, 60, SECONDS);
}

if (message.equals("!closeWWW")) {
     future.cancel(true);
}
```

However, when I send the !closeWWW command, myTask keeps running.

This is running off PircBot if it matters.

I apologize if this is a silly question but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code for myTask, which right now simply sends a message to the channel:

```
  public myTask() {

    public void run() {
        bot.sendMessage(channel, message);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to take the `Future` that is returned by the first method call and call [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) on it. Probably don't shut down the executor if you need it again - they're not free to create. In general **don't ignore the return values of methods**.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I updated the main post to reflect what you are saying, but it is still not working. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: We'll need to see the code for `myTask` - is your tasking blocking/looping?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have added the code for `myTask`